# How can I debug a spring integration / rabbitmq app on Cloud Foundry?

Tags: rabbitmq, cloud-foundry

I have deployed a multi node application to cloud foundry, all connected via a shared rabbitmq service. The application consists of:

- A grails app.
- 3 standalone spring-integration-amqp java apps.

All are communicating to rabbit via spring-integration-amqp, using cloud:rabbit-connection-factory.

All of the applications have the same rabbitmq service bound.

All of the applications start correctly and seem to connect to rabbit ok.

The behaviour I am seeing is that the grails app is timing out whilst waiting for a response from one of the standalone apps. This is consistent with me only starting up the grails app locally and not the message consumers.

What I am struggling with is how to debug where the problem is.

- I can't see any errors in the logs
- It doesn't seem possible to tunnel to the rabbitmq service in order to query the state of the queues etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: Even stranger, now it seems that the odd message get through, sometimes. So the configuration is obviously not fundamentally wrong... Just flawed somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Are you pushing to cloudfoundry.com or micro cloudfoundry?

To answer your questions:

1. Have you tried using "vmc file"? For java web applications cloudfoundry uses tomcat as the app server and you can use that command to navigate to tomcat/logs to have a look. Maybe some stdout was redirected there.
2. Did you have Caldecott installed? If you did not read this doc, here it is: http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/tools/vmc/caldecott.html

Comment: Thanks, I have been pushing to cloudfoundry.com. I have been using bmx files and cannot see any logged errors. I tried the Caldecott tunnelling route also, but the documentation (and another post on here) states that you cannot tunnel to the rabbitmq admin http process.

Comment: You can use "vmc tunnel service-name" to open a tunnel to the rabbitmq service. It will then prompt you to open a client against it. By accessing the tunnel, a url should be assembled under the format amqp://username:password@localhost:port/vhost.